# Tracking CPU usage on customer machine to detect high CPU usage process

Tags: windows, performance, cpu-usage

My customer complain that our window desktop application slow down sometimes. I don't see any strange in the my application log file. So I think that the CPU may be used by another application. So, is there any way (or tool) to track high CPU usage on client machine?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tool Performance monitor for the windows server.

You can track various processes CPU utilization (Processor time etc). This way you could track  on your processes particularly and can get CPU utilization for your processes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx